# Conjugation action $PU(H)\times Fred(H) \to Fred(H)$ is well defined

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be the - up to isomorphism - unique infinite dimensional seperable Hilbert Space. Consider the projective unitary group $PU(H)=U(H)/U(1)$, which acts by conugation
$$  PU(H)\times \operatorname{Fred}(H) \to \operatorname{Fred}(H), $$
$$ ([U],F)\mapsto UFU^* = UFU^{-1}.$$ Why is this action well defined? Group theoretic the question is clear, since we quotiened out the centre. But why is $UFU^* \in \operatorname{Fred}(H)$, i.e. a Fredholm operator? Building on the comment provided by Severin Schraven, how do I see that the dimension of the cokernel remains finite?

Comment: Please add "separable" before Hilbert space.

Comment: The conjugatated operator is bounded again as composition of bounded operators is again bounded. As the unitary operator is a bijection it also doesn't change the dimension of the kernel. So you just have to show that the dimension of cokernel also remains finite and you are done.

Comment: It seems that the comment above already answered your question?